# JpaRepository won't save data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I use JpaRepository to save data, but the hibernate.show_sql shows "select" and won't save data. Following is my service:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    User admin = new User();
    admin.setDisplayName("admin");
    admin.setEmailAddress("admin@admin");
    admin.setPassword("admin___");
    admin.setRegisteredAt(new Date());
    admin.setLastAccessAt(new Date());
    admin.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    try {
        System.out.println("before save");
        userRepository.save(admin);
        System.out.println("after save");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

========before save======

Hibernate: select user0_.uuid as uuid1_0_0_, user0_.display_name as display_2_0_0_, user0_.email_address as email_ad3_0_0_, user0_.last_access_at as last_acc4_0_0_, user0_.password as password5_0_0_, user0_.registered_at as register6_0_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.uuid=?

========after save=======

Following is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="test">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helloworld" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="myEmf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.entity"></property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="test.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="myEmf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"></jpa:repositories>
```

Attached is my class generated by JPA Tools:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String uuid;

  @Column(name="display_name")
  private String displayName;

  @Column(name="email_address")
  private String emailAddress;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name="last_access_at")
  private Date lastAccessAt;

  private String password;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name="registered_at")
  private Date registeredAt;

  public   User() {
  }

  public String getUuid() {
      return this.uuid;
  }

  public void setUuid(String uuid) {
      this.uuid = uuid;
  }

  public String getDisplayName() {
      return this.displayName;
  }

  public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
      this.displayName = displayName;
  }

  public String getEmailAddress() {
      return this.emailAddress;
  }

  public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
      this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
  }

  public Date getLastAccessAt() {
      return this.lastAccessAt;
  }

  public void setLastAccessAt(Date lastAccessAt) {
      this.lastAccessAt = lastAccessAt;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
      return this.password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
  }

  public Date getRegisteredAt() {
      return this.registeredAt;
  }

  public void setRegisteredAt(Date registeredAt) {
      this.registeredAt = registeredAt;
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the code you posted? Why would saving a new User issue a select query? Also, since you're using JPA, the transaction manager should be a JpaTransactionManager.

Comment: You are so great! After change to JpaTransactionManager, it works like a charm now.

Comment: It shows select first, then insert. Is this normal?  

========before save======
Hibernate: select user0_.uuid as uuid1_0_0_, user0_.display_name as display_2_0_0_, user0_.email_address as email_ad3_0_0_, user0_.last_access_at as last_acc4_0_0_, user0_.password as password5_0_0_, user0_.registered_at as register6_0_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.uuid=?
Hibernate: insert into User (display_name, email_address, last_access_at, password, registered_at, uuid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
========after save=======

Comment: My guess is that it's due to the facts that you assign IDs yourself instead of letting Hibernate do it, and you don't have any @Version annotated field, and you use merge() instead of persist(). Hibernate thus doesn't have any way to know if the entity already exists and should be updated, or if it doesn't exist yet and should be inserted.

Comment: I attached my class just now. I use uuid as primary key. If I use GeneratedValue, it has error to run. I am wondering how to add @Version and persis(). Thanks.

Comment: Then go to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/, search for uuid, and you'll see an example of annotations needed to use a uuid generator.

Comment: After using generator, it works now. I would like to accept your answer, but no marks to accept beside your answer.

Comment: I'll add a short answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using JPA, the transaction manager should be a `JpaTransactionManager`, not a `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

Comment: This is correct answer. After changing to org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager, my application works.